# How to call Java class in another class

Tags: java, android, class, methods

I'm new in Java and Android and I have lots of problems. I Create one Java class call EmptyField.java, this class has 2 methods: Login Empty and Create Empty.
I have another java file called Loginactivity.java. In Loginactivity I want to call EmptyField's class but I'm not able to do it. This is my code.

Emptyfield.java

```
package com.example.prenotazione_esame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EmptyField extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    }

    public String LoginEmpty(){

        EditText login_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserName);
        EditText password_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
        if ((login_text.getText().toString().equals(""))|| (password_text.getText().toString().equals(""))){
            return "Empty" ;
        }
        else{
            return "Full";
        }
    }
    public String CreateEmpty(){

        EditText login_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UserName);
        EditText password_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
        EditText conferma_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Conferma);
        if ((login_text.getText().toString().equals(""))|| (password_text.getText().toString().equals("")) || (conferma_text.getText().toString().equals(""))){
            return "Empty" ;
        }
        else{
            return "Full";
        }
    }
}
```

this is Loginactivity.java:

```
package com.example.prenotazione_esame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    private LoginDataBase dbLogin;
    EmptyField emptyf = new EmptyField();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Button button_crea = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Create);
        button_crea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                openCreateAccount();
            }
        });

        dbLogin = new LoginDataBase(this);

        Button button_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login);
        button_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                executeLogin();

            }
        });

    }
   private void openCreateAccount(){
       Intent intent_crea = new Intent(this, CreateAccountActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent_crea);
    }
   private void executeLogin(){

       //EmptyField emptyf = new EmptyField();
       String a=emptyf.LoginEmpty();
       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       toast.show();



   }
}
```

I start my app on the emulator and, when it try to call EmptyField class, the app crash. can ypou help me? Thank you.

my logcat:

```
05-08 09:24:49.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1162): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 09:24:49.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1162): Process: com.example.prenotazione_esame, PID: 1162
05-08 09:24:49.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1162): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 09:24:49.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at com.example.prenotazione_esame.LoginActivity.executeLogin(LoginActivity.java:55)
05-08 09:24:49.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at    com.example.prenotazione_esame.LoginActivity.access$1(LoginActivity.java:44)
05-08 09:24:49.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at com.example.prenotazione_esame.LoginActivity$2.onClick(LoginActivity.java:34)
05-08 09:24:49.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-08 09:24:49.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
05-08 09:24:49.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-08 09:24:49.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-08 09:24:49.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-08 09:24:49.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-08 09:24:49.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 09:24:49.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-08 09:24:49.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-08 09:24:49.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-08 09:24:49.070: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here my empyfield.java. Now it run. Thank you.

```
package com.example.prenotazione_esame;


import android.widget.EditText;

public class EmptyField{

    public String LoginEmpty(EditText x, EditText y){

        if ((x.getText().toString().equals(""))|| (y.getText().toString().equals(""))){
            return "Empty" ;
        }
        else{
            return "Full";
        }
    }
    public String CreateEmpty(EditText x, EditText y, EditText z){

        if ((x.getText().toString().equals(""))|| (y.getText().toString().equals("")) || (z.getText().toString().equals(""))){
            return "Empty" ;
        }
        else{
            return "Full";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's analyze the problem from a different perspective before fixing the code.. do you want to call an activity from another activity? Is that your goal?

Comment: Maybe my EmptyField.java is not an activity. I want just create a class that perform some task and I want use its methods in my app. Loginactivity, instead, is a activity. I want call EmptyField from LoginActivity. I'm so sorry but I have to create Android app but noone teach me Java. So I'm very new.

Comment: hmm ur trying to call a method of another activity....i have never tried dat which i doubt can be done...apart from that EmptyField class has its own widgets and they don't belong to the LoginActivity class so..that maybe a problem too..post ur logcat

Comment: If the EmptyField is not an activity then you extend the Activity class? There is the problem. Don't extend activity there and remove the life cycle methods. Write members, getters and setters alone.

Comment: As I understand, you want to show another screen (login screen) to user and get login and password from it, is it true?

Comment: As your code shows, both your classes ARE activities. If you don't want to use EmptyField as an Activity just do not extend Activity. At this point you should be able to call any method of EmptyField but other problems may arise, for example you are not allowed to modify and EditText box out of the scope of the activity without passing the Context. I suggest you to read a proper and easy guide about Android programming before going further.

Comment: The goal of EmptyField.java is: verify that the strings of the two edit text (Username and Password) is not "". Now I undesrtund that I don't have to extends activity, I have to create just a class. Can I do a class and passi it 2 parameters string? for exampe: EmptyField(string1 , string2).

Comment: Of course you can. And this is way better in terms of architecture

Comment: Great, Now I try to do this

Comment: If I create a EmptyField.java class, and not extends activity, Do I have to add EmptyField in my manifest.xml??

Comment: It run! It run, now all run good. Thank you very much guys. I will had my class in the question so you can see what I have done. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Your method is declared as private. Have you tried making it public?

```
private void executeLogin(){
```

Try changing it to.

```
public void executeLogin(){
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to show another screen with login and password fields, you need to use startActivityForResult() method:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

And at this case in EmptyField.onCreate() method you need to setContent (or you have not View to use findViewById() method).

Another way means that EmptyField is just helper class. So there are no reasons to extend Activity class. But in this case you must send your main view to LoginEmpty() method, and call findViewById for this view.

Answer (score 0):

EmptyField will not work calling `findViewById()` will need to `setContentView()` in that activity each activity have they own life cycle if you want to access those component maybe passing those component inside bundle not sure.
But in your case i would just create a simple class and pass those component you don't really need extend Activity in your case.